# Code and dataset(small size) for image clustering

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, kaggle

Can anyone pls provide code and dataset for Unsupervised image clustering. There is no resources are available on the internet regarding image clustering and its implementation

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for some tutorial with dataset and python code examples, here you will find some examples.

1. Keras & Sklearn for binary (cat or dog) clustering.

https://towardsdatascience.com/image-clustering-using-k-means-4a78478d2b83

2. Combining CNN and K-Means for multilabel clustering. (Data from Kaggle). At the end you can find all the code.

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-cluster-images-based-on-visual-similarity-cd6e7209fe34